# Open activity when a widget is added (not only once)

Tags: android, android-activity, widget

I have a widget that is configured through an activity (I do not want to do it through a `preference activity`) and would like to have the configuration activity to open each and every time a widget is added.

Once the user configures the widget, the data is saved in an XML.

I see that `onEnable()` works only the first time a widget is added, my question is: is there any other function that is called every time a widget is added?

I have considered adding the widgetId to the XML and check every time the `onUpdate()` is called if there is a new widgetId that is not in the XML file, but I guess that is very messy.

Can anyone give me some hint here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When user add new instance of your widget,`onUpdate` and `onReceive` methods of your AppWidgetProvider will be invoked.You can try to start Activity when those invoked.
**Edit**:
To detect that user add new instance of your widget,you would to save `int[] appWidgetIds`(this is array of unique IDs of your widget instances) when `onUpdate` and `onReceive` method are invoked(probably you have to save it in App preferences or file or ...).Then when onUpdate or onReceive  invoked agaain,check that `length of newest appWidgetIds is greater than length of latest appWidgetIds` or no?If it was true,you can sure that user added new instance ,if both be equal,one of your widget updated normally and if newest length be less than latest length,you can sure that user deleted on of your widget instances.In `onUpdate` and `onReceive` ,Finally save `appWidgetIds` again and so on.

Comment: Yes, but 'OnUpdate' is called every time the widget updates (every 30 min) and I only want to start the activity when the user adds the new widget.

Comment: OK, I assume that if a widget is deleted and added again and deleted and added again... the widget id will never show up again, right?

Comment: @luanjot I don't know.I offer you to check length of them.